# A single adjective for 'too big to fit'

Tags: single-word-requests

Does something like this exist? A single word with the meaning "taking up more space than available".

Use case: Excel sheet name (<30 characters) that lists values that do not fit because their columns have a shorter maximum length. Ideally, the sheet's name is '[adjective I'm looking for] values'.

Options I found so far:

- *shortened values* means something different, but might be the best I can think of in this case, since the part at the end that doesn't fit is cut off.
- *truncated values* like the last one, but possibly more accurate, and maybe more confusing at the same time, since in a database 'truncate' usually means losing the entire table content.
- *values that did not fit* is a pretty descriptive name that fits, but has two verbs and is almost a sentence; therefore it feels too extensive for a sheet name to me.

I did not expect it to be difficult to find the right words for something as common as this, but even in my primary language Dutch I can't find the right formulation. In Dutch I would probably say 'te grote waarden', which does not sound grammatically correct in English ('too big values').

Comment: How about “too long”?

Comment: The values are too long indeed, but I can't say that I have a list of *too long values*. It seems to be an English grammatical limitation...

Comment: You could say too-long values, though, or values that are too long. But why not just change the width of the column? Or wrap the text?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen it used before in this particular context, but *outsized* might fit:

> : an unusual size
>   *especially* : a size larger than the standard

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outsized))

Comment: Or _oversized_.

Comment: *Outsized* and *oversized* are not bad, thank you. But I think they both mean '(much) bigger than usual' rather than 'bigger than could possibly ever fit'.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two different ways of interpreting this question, so I'll provide an answer to each.

Let's say you have the word *anthropomorphize*, which is 16 characters, and that the spreadsheet has cells that only allow for 10 characters.

You then have two different pieces of text: *anthropomo* (10 characters) and *anthropomorphize* (16 characters).

---

### 1. *Anthropmo* is …

As a better word than *shortened* or *truncated*, I would say that *anthropomo* is the [**displayed**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/display) value:

> [Merriam-Webster: *display*]
> **1 a** : to put or spread before the view
> // *display* the flag.

---

### 2. *Anthropomorphize* is …

This depends on further interpretation. I will give two possibilities.

a) *Anthropomorphize* is the [**actual**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/actual) value:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1 a** : existing in fact or reality
> // *actual* events
> // *actual* and imagined conditions
> **1 b** : not false or apparent
> // *actual* costs

b) *Anthropomorphize* is the [**extended**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extended) value:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **2 a** : fully stretched out
> // an *extended* battle line

While *extended* can mean to expand or stretch something beyond its original size, in this case it would be relative to the number of characters being displayed.

---

The following is a summary:

- *Anthropomo* is the **displayed** (10-character) value of the **actual** word *anthropomorphize*.
- *Anthropomorphize* is the **extended** (16-character) value of the same word.